# SQL Check Tree Branch for record

Tags: sql, sql-server, tree

[Example Tree Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P3GoG.jpg)

Using MS SQL SERVER.

### RELEVANT TABLE STRUCTURES

Table 1 core_person

```
person_id, first_name, last_name
    1        Joe          Doe
    2        Jill         Doe
```

Table 2 core_profile

```
profile_id, parent_profile_id, profile_name
    1             NULL          Main Campus
    2              1            Adult
    3              2            Usher
    4              1            Children
    5              4            Teacher
```

Table 3 core_profile_member

```
profile_id, person_id
    3           1
    5           2
    5           1
```

### DESIRED OUTPUT

Based on the sample data provided the desired output would be as seen below

```
person_id, first_name, last_name, Adults, Childrens
    1         Joe        Doe        T        T
    2         Jill       Doe        F        T
```

New to SQL - I understand how to build a tree structure but I have no idea how to search through specific parts of it.

I need to be able to search each of the tree branches and return a true/false for each "Department" for whether the individual is serving. So if the person_id appears in any tag under the Adults branch Return True. So far I was able to tweak a Tree Query I found online to specify the top level campus tag, but I have no idea how to recursively check through the individual records.

```
WITH Serving_Tree AS (
-- Anchor query: Get the root records
SELECT profile_id, parent_profile_id, profile_name
FROM core_profile
-- This parent_profile_id would be the Campus tag
WHERE parent_profile_id = '448'

UNION ALL

-- Recursive query: Get the records of the next level
SELECT child.profile_id, child.parent_profile_id, child.profile_name
FROM core_profile AS child
INNER JOIN Attrs AS parent 
ON child.parent_profile_id = parent.profile_id
)
SELECT profile_id, parent_profile_id,profile_name
FROM Serving_Tree
```

Comment: Can we see some sample data?

Comment: Edited to add sample data. Let me know if you have any other questions.